# synchronous actions in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

The first action (adding the div), is done fine.
The second action (loading the content) is done fine.
The third action, isn't happening. I need to remove something in the loaded content. Can somehow please explain how to do that?

```
$('#eucontentpage #country-choice .lang-ico').click(function(){
    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function() {
        $.when(
            $("#insertnationalcontent").load(loadlink)
        ).done(function() {
            $('#insertnationalcontent .lightbox').remove()
        }); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, but have you heard of `$.then`? http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ It allow you to chain AJAX request like that : http://jsfiddle.net/470ak2oq/

Comment: `.after()` inserts content _after_ the target element , `.lightbox` would _not_ be a child element of `#insertnationalcontent` based on call to `after()` http://api.jquery.com/after/ at this line `$('#insertnationalcontent .lightbox').remove()` ? If possible , can post `html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the load callback function in steead of the when/done structure.

```
$('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')

$('#insertnationalcontent').load(loadlink, function() {
        $('#insertnationalcontent .lightbox').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For reasons known only to the jQuery developers, the `.load()` function doesn't return a promise, so you can't usefully use it with `.when` - the effect will be that the `.when` call will immediately invoke the callback, and then sometime later the new content will appear.

The plugin below creates an alternate version of `.load` that does return a promise instead:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.promiseLoad = function(url, data) {
        var jqObj = this;
        return $.Deferred(function(def) {
            jqObj.load(url, data, def.resolve);
        }).promise();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think that's it, because I solved it by using the load callback function in stead of the when/done structure.

Answer (score 0):

`remove` should end properly with a `semi-colon` as it's a statement inside an anonymous function in `done` unlike the arguments you pass to `when`

```
$('#eucontentpage #country-choice .lang-ico').click(function(){
    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function() {
        $.when(
            $("#insertnationalcontent").load(loadlink)
        ).done(function() {
            $('#insertnationalcontent .lightbox').remove();
        }); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change a thing for me

Comment: without seeing your html, it's hard to tell, can you post the html in your question >

Comment: i'll think about adding html, but it's quite complicated. But when i add jQuery('.lightbox').length in the done, it alerts 0

Comment: which done ? 1st one or 2nd one ? also one more doubt regarding structure, you're adding `insertnationalcontent` after `lightbox`, then loading html into `insertnationalcontent` but after it's done, you're trying to delete `lighbox` inside `insertnationalcontent`, so does the html received in `load()` contain another `lightbox` element ??

Answer (score 0):

[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after) inserts content *after* the target element , `.lightbox` would not be a child element of `#insertnationalcontent` based on call to `after()`  at this line `$('#insertnationalcontent .lightbox').remove()`

Note, Not certain about `html`

```
$('#eucontentpage #country-choice .lang-ico').click(function(){
    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function(elem) {
      elem.siblings("#insertnationalcontent")
      .load(loadlink, function() {
        $(this).prev(".lightbox").remove()
       }); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

```js
var loadlink = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/49fbc054731540fa68b565e398d3574fde7366e9/abc.txt";

$('#eucontentpage #country-choice .lang-ico').click(function(){
    $.when(
        $('.lightbox').after('<div id="insertnationalcontent"></div>')
    ).done(function(elem) {
      elem.siblings("#insertnationalcontent")
      .load(loadlink, function() {
        $(this).prev(".lightbox").remove()
       }); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="eucontentpage">
  <div id="country-choice">
     <div class="lang-ico">
       click
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lightbox">
  lightbox
  </div>
```

Comment: With the load, there should come a lightbox as well in the #insertnationalcontent